# Installing swagger throws a warning of dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, mocking, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to install Swagger through npm by this link.. When I install it, it gives me warning message like below-

```
npm WARN swagger-express-middleware@1.0.0-alpha.12 requires a peer of express@4.x but none was installed.
```

What should I do to remove this warning?

Comment: Install `express` first.

Answer (score 0):

This error says that `express` is not installed. Run

```
npm install --save express
```

first, and then repeate swagger installation.